# Adding J Query datepicker to django forms

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker, django-forms, calendar

So I've been trying to add a J Query datepicker (calendar thing) to my django code for about a week, and I'm getting nowhere. I've been trying soo many tutorials to no avail- so I'm needing some help. I'm pretty new to django, but my job needs me to add this datepicker to a site.

Here's my forms.py:

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['animal_id','species_strain','dob', 'dod', 'sex', 'source', 'parents', 'labloc', 'notes']
        widgets ={
                    'dob':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
                    "dod":forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day")),
                    "parents":SelectMultiple(),
        }
```

Here's my views.py:

```
def addAnimal(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    aform = forms.AnimalForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    aform.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
    aform.fields['dod'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
    if aform.is_valid():
        animal = aform.save(commit=False)
        animal.save()
        return redirect('/input')
else:
    aform = forms.AnimalForm()
return render(request, 'lab/input.html', {'aform':aform})
```

And finally, here's my html template:

```
  <!-- date picker html -->
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dob" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
 });
} );
</script>
```

I hope this makes sense, according to the tutorials I've been doing, everything should be right but I honestly don't know. I admittedly don't know what I'm doing, but I don't have a choice lol. I'm trying to use the J Query datepicker on their site, and I honestly can't figure out whats wrong. Please help

Comment: `$( "id_dob" )` is an invalid selector.  If you are wanting to find an element by an id of dob then you need `$( "#dob" )`.  Othewise, what your selector is currently trying to find is an element of `<id_dob>` which is not a real thing

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  I highly recommend you give the entirety of the learn.jquery.com site a chance, as it has lots of good material.

Comment: @Taplar hey thanks! So I edited my code and changed the selector, but it still doesn't work :( I'll definitely go through that link though!

Comment: Why are you loading multiple versions of jQuery.js and jQuery-ui.js? Only load one of each not three of each